# GCP Managed Instance verification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a GCP Managed Instance Group with 1 instance running Windows Server. The VM is created and I ran the below code to confirm the instance is RUNNING.

```
gcloud compute instances describe <instance name>
```

However console is showing a spinning wheel next to the VM name and it says "Instance is being verified". It has been like this for more than 2 hours. Occasionally, there would be an exclamation mark saying "The resource 'projects/(proj name)/zones/(zone name)/instances/(instance name)' is not ready".

Then after a while, the spinning wheel's message changes to "Instance is being recreated".

I cannot RDP into the server because the instance is still being verified or recreated. How do I overcome this?

Is this an issue with the instance template?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create a health check and configure it with correct firewall rules?

Comment: Yes... health check failed as VM is unavailable but firewall rules verified okay (another similar VM running). I am suspecting there is something wrong with the snapshot that I used to build the template.

Comment: Those error report are more generic. Have you tried to create the managed instance group using the [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances#create_managed_group)? This would provide more details about the error in the CLI. We would be then able to troubleshoot the issue by looking the error report.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I can now confirm it has to do with the instance template... more specifically the snapshot which was used to build the template. I retook a new snapshot to built the template, and updated the instance with this new template and it works.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Can you please elaborate how was it solved?

Comment: GalAbra, shutdown your VM. Then create your snapshot and use that snapshot to convert to image and use the image to create a template instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a problem with your instance template. It happens to me occasionally when I make a new template and apply it where my instance will sit there spinning forever saying instance is being verified. Revert to an older template if you can (or make a new one from an instance snapshot) and replace the instance.